# My image gallery: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I tried adding new implementations to see if I could bypass the issue to get the gradle to build but it didn't work just kept telling me of the this issue.

```
[Fatal Error] core-1.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] vectordrawable-1.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:kapt'.
   > Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0 > androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0
         project :app > com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0 > androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0
         project :app > com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0 > androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0
         project :app > com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0 > androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 > androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0
         project :app > com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0 > androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 > androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0
         project :app > com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0 > androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 > androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0
         project :app > com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0 > androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 > androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0
         project :app > com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0 > androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 > androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0
         project :app > com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0 > androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 > androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0
         project :app > com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0 > androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 > androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0
         project :app > com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0 > androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 > androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0
      > Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.0.0.
         > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.0.0/core-1.0.0.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0 > androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0
      > Could not resolve androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0.
         > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/vectordrawable/vectordrawable/1.0.0/vectordrawable-1.0.0.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Gradle Build for the module

[image]

Gradle build

[image]

Manifest

[image]

screenshot of the error

[image]

I use Kotlin

[Implemented BlackSamurai advice, managed to get this in the end, I don't know if it works though, I will try it now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M87G6.png)

So I managed to get the build to build successfully, I ran the emulator to see if my image gallery worked or not and I got this:

[I think my images are hiding in the corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Woy2f.png)

Comment: Can you post your build files and/or code? It helps to have that along with the error.

Comment: im trying to add the gradle at this current moment but overflow wont let me , keeps telling me to indent it four times before posting it which i did but keeps preventing me from doing so. please wait a bit more thank you

Comment: gradle code uploaded plus manifest

Comment: Please don't post text data as images / screenshots

Comment: James Z, I would post the actual code but stack overflow wont let me indent my post hence I have to resort to images and screen shot.

Comment: Stack Overflow really will allow you to use code formatting - this very post contains post formatting. Please try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a transitive dependency in one of your files. You need to force the use of `android.core.1.0.0`:

```
implementation('androidx.core:core:1.0.0') {
    force = true
}
```

You may also need to do the same for the `vectorDrawable`:

```
    implementation('androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0') {
        force = true
    }
```

You should also add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`
 to your manifest.

Comment: So i made the changes in my code by replacing the ones you mentioned as well as adding the access network state command as well and nothing seems to have changed. Also I couldnt use this "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$version" it kept failing to resolve so I used this instead " androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.0-alpha02".  Although everything seemed to be successful upon syncing the gradle after the changes above, when I clicked " make build" the errors I mentioned above appeared so yea. I figured even if I was to hit "run" the same result would show as well.

Comment: @DragonicShadowWalker see my updated answer.

Comment: So I tried implementing the changes you mentioned within your edited comment. After making those changes the gradle was synced successfully but when the program was executed I received the same errors : [Fatal Error] core-1.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] vectordrawable-1.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: this part of the code was based off this websites :https://thesimplycoder.com/137/android-image-gallery-using-kotlin-tutorial/ - Im trying to the image gallery on my end to work. Im starting to think it might a configuration error within my Manifest but im not so sure.

Comment: Did you add all the: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

Comment: You can also try just using `glide.4.8.0` instead of 4.9.0

Comment: yes , i have all of those apply plugins implemented as well

Comment: ill see if changing glide 4.9 to 4.8 will have any change, i just did it , after syncing it, I clicked " Make Project" instead of having the  [Fatal Error] vectordrawable-1.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog. and the latter now I only have [Fatal Error] core-1.0.0.pom:2:1

Comment: I just made a few changes myself , I took of one of the kapt glide implementations, now i have these 2 left implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0' After doing this and clicking "Make Project" I managed to get get the above result.

Comment: Looks like it worked. Good luck :)

Comment: yea it finally worked but now the image gallery is hiding my images , see the post I just made a  moment ago, you mind helping me out once again. I really appreciate and am really grateful that you are taking your time to teach me. I thank you for that

Comment: knock knock samurai you there?

Comment: The image issue would be another question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57588015/trying-to-resolve-an-issue-image-is-hiding-at-the-corner-of-the-screen-when-i this is the link to the other question I made abot the image gallery not working and so forth